# Nontrivial normed functional on the bounded functions from $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$ invariant by isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, linear-transformations, isometry

I am trying to show that there exists a nontrivial normed functional on $\mathbb R^2$ invariant by isometries. That is:

If $A$ is any set, let $\mathcal B_{A}=\{f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R: f \text{ is bounded}\}$. Let $\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x)|: x \in  A\}$. Notice that we are dealing with a vector space.

I am looking for a linear functional satisfying:

- $I$ is normed, that is, $|I(f)|\leq \|f\|$
- $I$ is nontrivial, that is, $I(1)=1$
- If $s \in \mathbb R^2$, let $f_s(x)=f(x+s)$ for every $x \in X$ and let $f^-(x)=f(\bar x)$ (complex conjugation). There are the translations and reflections. If $|t|=1$, let $f^t(x)=f(tx)$ (complex product). We want that $I(f)=I(f^-)=I(f_s)=I(f^t)$. These are the rotations.

I have already proved that there exists $I_0$ satisfies everything but the rotation thing.

Let $T=\{z: |z|=1\}$. I also know that there exists a nontrivial normed linear functional $I_1: \mathcal B_T \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying $I_1(f^t)=I(f)$ for every $t \in \mathbb T$, $f \in \mathcal B_T$.

The book I am following tells me to define $I(f)=I_1(G_f)$, where $G_f: \mathcal B_t \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by $G_f(t)=I_0(f^t)$. This is a bounded function since $\|f^t\|=\|f\|$. It's easy to see that $I$ is a nontrivial normed linear functional. I have verified that $I$ is invariant by rotations and by translations, but I'm stuck on showing $I$ is invariant by the reflection.

My attempt to show it was:

Notice that $(f^-)^t(x)=f(\bar t \bar x)=(f^{\bar t})^-(x)$. Therefore, $G_{\bar f}(t)=G_f(\bar t)$ since $I_0$ is invariant by $\,^-$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

I'm tagging this question as measure theory since I need to prove this in order to define a nice measure on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: may duplicate to :http://mathoverflow.net/q/44183/74330

Comment: Why exactly do you need such a functional? To obtain a measure, it would suffice to have a functional on $C_c$ or $C_0$, via the riesz representation theorem. But on $C_c$ a functional satisfying your requirements will vanish.

Comment: Also, the book possibly means to take $I_1(t\mapsto I_0(f^t))$.

Comment: Hello PhoemueX, I think the book really means to take this function. I have done so and edited my question.